# Речі для немовлят українською

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, етимологія

На сайті [Мова -ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/antusurzhuk/rechi-dlya-nemovlyat-ukrayinskoyu) побачила цікаву картинку [image]
Майже всі слова знайомі та мають зрозуміле вживання, а ось із слово ***"дурник"*** дещо не зовсім.

***Яке походження має дане слово? Якими ще може бути переклад російського слова "пустишка" ?***

На цьому ж сайті під картинкою є декілька варіантів - *смочо́к, пи́пка, мізю́к.* Проте В СУМ є визначення лише слова **[пипка](http://sum.in.ua/s/pypka)**, але не в значені ***"пустишка"***.

Comment: Я сам з російськомовного регіону, від людей, які розмовляють українською з народження я чув здебільшого дурник. Також вживають соска, але гадаю, що це суржик.

Comment: Обговорення цієї ж картинки: [на сторінці Yuliia Serhiienko](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=162584635282857&set=a.120402792834375) (див. також поширення), [у групі «УКРАЇНСЬКА МОВА ДЛЯ ВСІХ»](https://www.facebook.com/groups/367613903441695/permalink/1522596357943438/), [у групі «Україномовні Мами»](https://www.facebook.com/groups/318381818513962/permalink/1134284343590368/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

До наведених Вами варіантів додам:

- Со́ска — літературне слово ([«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/soska)).
- Пусту́шка — можливо, груба калька, але зафіксовано нормативними документами, зокрема [«Єдиним закупівельним словником (ДК 021:2015)»](http://search.ligazakon.ua/l_doc2.nsf/link1/ST002368.html) під номером [33711770-5](//ezs.dkpp.rv.ua/index.php?search=33711770-5&type=code).
- Є ще «цмочок» (замість «смочок»).

  <sub>Микола Устиянович (1811–1885), [«Взріст»](http://litopys.org.ua/zahpysm/zah17.htm):</sub>

  > <sub>«Нащо ти ся, доню, твориш
  >
  >   Та на Івасенька?
  >
  >   Таж він тебе з тяжка возьме,
  >
  >   Бо-сь му ще маленька».</sub>
  >
  > <sub>«За взріст ви ся не журіте,
  >
  >   Золота мамейко,
  >
  >   Таже я ж му сього року
  >
  >   Вгнала по серденько.</sub>
  >
  > <sub>А як ся лиш трошки випну
  >
  >   І на пальцях стану,
  >
  >   То легонько аж до личка
  >
  >   По **цмочок** дістану».</sub>

  <sub>Наталя Хобзей, Ксеня Сімович, Тетяна Ястремська, Ганна Дидик-Меуш, [«Лексикон львівський: поважно і на жарт»](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Khobzei_Natalia/Leksykon_lvivskyi_povazhno_i_na_zhart/), Львів, 2009, ст. 611:</sub>

  > <sub>**[цмо́чок](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53414/1068252.html)** соска (для немовлят) (м, ср, ст) || **дурачок**</sub>
- Є ще «музю́к» (замість «мізю́к»; до речі, обидва варіанти наводить [«Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm), каже, що можливо, походять від «ми́зати» = «торкатися мордою, лизати»), і пропонує порівняти з «ми́дза»/«ми́ґза»/«ми́за» = «морда, товсте обличчя, рило»).
- Ще люди кажуть:

  - «смоктунець» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187257564643343&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D), [2](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187496704619429&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R5%22%7D)), «смоктушка» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1188109854558114&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R0%22%7D)), «цмокталка» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187361764632923&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D)), «цмочка» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187403941295372&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D)) і «цмулик» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187441584624941&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R8%22%7D); очевидно від «[цму́лити](http://sum.in.ua/s/cmulyty)»);
  - «пустунчик» і «пустунка» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187257564643343&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D));
  - «обманка» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/675638002471971/?comment_id=675763532459418&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R4%22%7D)) і «дурачок» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/675638002471971/?comment_id=676737439028694&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R1%22%7D), [2](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187260394643060&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D), [3](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187557031280063&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R3%22%7D));
  - «лялька» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187300681305698&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D), [2](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187479521287814&reply_comment_id=1187498001285966&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D)) і «папа» ([1](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/?comment_id=1187479521287814&reply_comment_id=1187498001285966&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R9%22%7D)).

Наявність варіанту «обманка» для мене особисто натякає, що «дурник» і «дурачок» позначають не те, що сама соска — дурний предмет, а те, що вона обманює/дурить дитину.

Обговорення:

- [У групі «Український переклад» на Facebook № 2](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/675638002471971/).
- [У групі «Український переклад» на Facebook № 3](//www.facebook.com/groups/ukrpereklad/permalink/1187253777977055/).